# On the limit defined by $A + B(A + B(A + B (A + B(\cdots))))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, telescopic-series

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are some constant ($A,B\in\mathbb{R}$)

**Is there a simple expression for $x$, where $x$ is:**

$$
x=A+B[A+B[A+B[\cdots]]]]
$$
"..." indicates the pattern repeats forever.

In other words, it is recursive:
$$
x=A+Bx
$$

It is very tempting to just do:
$$
x=\frac{A}{1-B}
$$

However, is this correct? I don't think is that simple.

For context, I come from an engineering background and my math isn't as rigorous. Please enlighten me. Does this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) resembles this kind of series?

**Edit 1:**
I don't think the expression for $x$ is simple, because:
$$
x\neq \frac{A}{1-B}
$$

Comment: In the case where it converges, I think it is as simple as x = A/(1-B). However, in the case it diverges, for example B>1, is there a non-recursive expression for x?

Comment: When $B>1$ the sequence diverges as you note.  The below answer has the closed form for the $n$th term for all cases.

Comment: Kind of, Thank you so much. However, what is x_0? and can we know its value when n approach infinity for the case B>1?

Comment: $x_0$ is the initial value of the sequence; it is fixed.

Comment: Well, is a bit hard for me to type the whole situation of this. But we don't know x_0 in the first place? Only A and B are defined in the beginning. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your recurrence relation should have some initial condition. Think about it as an engineer: If I gave you the mechanics for how a system evolves, but don't tell you the system's starting state, how can you predict its behavior?  $x_0$ is the starting state, and $A,B$ tell us how the system evolves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144397/discussion-between-john-apple-and-golden-ratio).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041571/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given recurrence relation

$$x_{n+1}=A+Bx_{n},$$

induction shows

$$x_{n}=\begin{cases}
B^{n}x_{0}+A\frac{1-B^{n}}{1-B} & B\neq1\\
x_{0}+nA & B=1
\end{cases}.$$

If $|B|<1,$ then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\frac{A}{1-B}.$$